# Java Binary Number Syntax Error

Tags: java, binary, syntax-error

The following code results in a "Syntax error on token "b1000", delete this token". I've worked with binary numbers prior and this method of initialization worked fine so I'm not sure what's causing this particular error. Any help is appreciated. Currently running the latest version of Java, 8.

```
public class program {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=0b1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using at least Java 7?

Comment: The `0b...` syntax for binary literals is a new feature since Java 7; if you are using an older version of Java then it doesn't work and you'll get an error.

Comment: I've updated Java to version 8 but the error still persists.

Comment: Make sure that source and target of compilation are >= 7. Probably the IDE is set to 1.6. You could try an other java 8 feature too, streams for instances.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using Java 7 or above: "Binary literals can only be used with source level 1.7 or greater".

Answer (score 1):

This feature for *binary* literals was introduced with Java 7 (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html) for example).

In that sense you must be using a java compiler prior Java 7 (as your source code is valid for Java7 and newer).